# Name server configuration issues

Tags: dns, webmin, nameservers

I know this is a bit of an odd request but it is all Google's fault... So that being said I'm a university student and I have my own website for the purpose of marketing my self to potential employers for co-op.

Okay, the actually question is: I set my MX record using 1&1's name server to point to Google apps however I never bothered to set up a webserver, just mail. Now I need an actually website as interviews start soon but every host wants me to point to their name servers, the only problem being the moment my MX record switches Google apps will stop my account and mail services and I can't re register because Google apps is now only for enterprise customers and I just love gmail too much to risk losing it. So, is there any way I can determine the IP address the host is using and point my website too it, like in CPANEL? or do I absolutely have to use their name server... I'm tempted to just set up an old PC with webmin in my father's basement if I can't find a way to point directly to an IP.

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use 1&1 hosting too?

They provide [Windows](http://www.1and1.com/windows-hosting) and [Linux](http://www.1and1.com/linux-web-hosting) Hosting

If you aren't willing to do that, call up your hosting support. They should be able to determine the IP address you will need for you A Record.

More on [A Records](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/domains/domainfeatures/advanceddns/advanceddns-04.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response, Unfortunately 1&1 does not use CPANEL or webmin which are the two control panels I am familiar with. I believe the A record is listed as the shared IP adress on CPANEL... Is that correct? however I don't think the domain will know hot to go to my accounts public_html folder... or am I mistaking what the record is?

Comment: The A record tells the DNS where to look for yoru info when you enter your domain name in a browser. Like if you open a CMD prompt (assuming windows) and type Ping Google.com, your computer sends Google.com to a DNS resolver, and they'd return the A record IP address. Your host, whichever one you chose, should be able to tell you the IP address you need to set up. In their server, they will handle where the web site points.  If it's public_html, they will have that listed in their system. If it's somewhere else, they have that too. There are lots of DNS tutorials on the web you could examine.